# Is there a name for the areas on a web page where clicks do nothing?

Tags: terminology, technical

Sometimes I just want to click on a web page to give focus to that browser tab, and it can be hard in some richly functional web pages to find a bit of "blank space" to click on, where clicking won't trigger any action.

Is there a technical word for these "inert" areas on web pages?

Comment: Uh, "unclickable"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Questions about specialized terminology are usually better-handled by subject matter experts; our sister site [ux.SE] may be of interest.

Comment: ...a dead spot? This may belong on another site.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are many technical terms to refer to different elements of a webpage. You are not necessarily asking about the "background" (that's the term that comes to my mind) of the page, although I did find several references to that under webpage elements and design. Sometimes the background can be "clickable" anyway.

I don't think it's a technical term, but perhaps the word you are looking for is **"non-interactive"**. Any portion of a webpage can be described as **"non-interactive"** (background, images, text etc.), and clicking there elicits no action. I have seen that word used several times when referring to webpage content.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/noninteractive

https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-differentiate-between-interactive-and-non-interactive-websites